# Celery + Eventlet + Scrapy

Tags: scrapy, celery, eventlet

I have developed a crawler using scrapy and integrated it inside celery tasks. It runs well, without any problem.

Scrapy is based on twisted reactor, so as the scrapy docs said, "Scrapy runs a single spider per process". My question is "There is a way to run a spider inside a thread?" Or "Can i run scrapy crawler with celery eventlet"?

Thanks!